# How do I change the text of 10 text layers simultaneously?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

I downloaded a custom image, it's like gold font, and it consists of 10 different text layers. Whenever I click on a text layer to edit it, and to change my text, it will just go to the topmost layer. Making it impossible for me to edit it. It would be really great if I could change the text in all the layers at the same time. That might now be possible. I think I did change the text one layer at a time but i had to make all the layers invisible one by one. Is there any easier way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: I remembered how I did it last time. I double click on the T in the picture above and it lets me edit a specific layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what the text content is, you might be able to use **[Find and Replace Text](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-text.html#find_and_replace_text)** to accomplish this. It can be applied to a layer selection (rather than All Layers), allowing you to filter out text you may not need to change. Make sure those layers are visible and unlocked.

[image: Find and Replace demonstration]